# How do I tell the type of a field passed into a custom Html.DisplayFor helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I write a custom `DisplayFor` helper, for example:

```
public static HtmlString MyDisplayFieldFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object additionalViewData = null)
{

    //...

}
```

How do I determine the type of the field being passed into it such that different types can have custom display logic?

For example, I can all this method with three types:

```
@Html.MyDisplayFieldFor(e=>e.Name)  //string  
@Html.MyDisplayFieldFor(e=>e.DepartmentSelectList)  //SelectList
@Html.MyDisplayFieldFor(e=>e.CupsOfTeaPerDay) // int
```

What's the best way to access this type information inside the Helper method?

Comment: get type of TValue ie `typeof(TValue)`

Comment: `ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);` and then `metadata.ModelType` will give your the `type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value type from the expression

```
public static HtmlString MyDisplayFieldFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object additionalViewData = null) {

    var valueType = typeof(TValue);
    //...other code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the type of the passed value. ASP.NET MVC lets you create [display templates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html) that are automatically selected based on the type of the field.

You could for example create this template for the `SelectList` in your example and place it in the `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SelectList.cshtml` project folder.

```
@model SelectList

<!-- Replace this with the display code you prefer -->
<div class="select-list">@Model.ToString()</div>
```

This lets you keep the HTML code within the views.